# Cores mudando conforme o monitor

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um site para uso na empresa em que trabalho, esse site tem o fundo azul e tudo mais, no meu notebook ele fica lindo, a cor azul que escolhi mesmo, mas quando mudo para outro monitor ele fica roxo, uma cor totalmente fora da minha escala, estou fazendo algo de errado ou pode ser o monitor mesmo?

Comment: Compra um monitor bom.

Comment: O monitor é um LG 20M37AA-B, acredito ser  um excelente monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- O ideal é sempre usar a referência RGB ou Hexadecimal da cor que deseja aplicar. Acredito que o azul do fundo do site está pautado em alguma cor que esteja no logo da empresa ou alguma forma de material;
- Se essa referência não existir, recomendo a **[paleta de cores do Material Design do Google](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette)**
- De qualquer forma, para garantir a fidelidade, verifique o perfil de cor do monitor, ou restaure para as configurações de fábrica.

Comment: Estou utilizando a escala RGBA pois quero deixar o backgroud-color um pouco mais "Transparente" digamos assim, isso pode impactar na mudança de cores de monitor para monitor?

Comment: @LuixxxCosta se você está usando `rgba` para o fundo apenas para ter uma cor mais clara, é ideal achar essa referência exata de cor em Hexadecimal ou RGB, mas, ainda assim, os valores são constantes e não variam por si entre monitores. O monitor que você está usando está, provavelmente, descalibrado.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode acontecer são duas coisas:

- A mudança de browser impactar na correta exibição das cores (o que é extremamente **improvável**, já que é uma mudança sutil e só ocorre quando as cores são definidas como "red", "blue", etc.. ao invés do uso do *RGB, HSL*...)
- Realmente um dos monitores não possui uma fidelidade de cor muito boa ou troca no **HUE** (provavelmente)

Para referências:

[HUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) (wikipedia em inglês)

Exemplo de sites para teste de monitor: [Vanity.dk](http://tft.vanity.dk/monitorTest_scale.html) e [LCD Monitor Test](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) .